upgrade to 24.04.1 uninstall snap and lxd
I had ubuntu 22.04.5 LTE after upgraded to 24.04.1 LTE I cannot find snap & lxd on my server :(((
Upgraded by do-release-upgrade command.
Why it happened and How to restore my containers now ?

Please edit your question to show us the complete output of apt list snapd. Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Desktop or another flavor?
